Nginx get time spent in cache lock
In Nginx, I am using the cache lock mechanism to control requests that make it's way to the upstream. However recently I noticed that, when there is a problem in the upstream, some requests take a lot of time, and most of them spend time in the cache lock. But what I see from my logs is this:
HIT 600s
HIT 601s

Very high request_time in HIT requests, and they are labeled as HIT because they were waiting in the cache lock. But this made me think our cache disks were failing (they were not, it was upstream that was failing).
Is there a way to distinguish the time spent in cache lock?
Or label that log like HIT_LOCK instead of HIT?
Or something to connect the cache locked request to the first/initial MISS one that locked the cache?
